# How do you configure and use the gulp eslint task?

Tags: gulp, eslint, gulp-eslint

I'm trying to get gulp-eslint working. Here is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^5.0.0",
}
```

There was no mention of dependencies on the gulp-eslint [Github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-eslint) page but when I first ran my `gulp lint` task, I was prompted to install `eslint-plugin-babel` so I assume it is required.

Here is my task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    gulp.src('js/scripts.js)
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Here is my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "rules": {}
}
```

When I run `gulp lint` I get this error:

```
Error: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc is invalid:
- Unexpected top-level property "parseOptions"
```

The eslint docs use `parserOptions` so I'm not sure where `parseOptions` is coming from. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after installing a whole bunch of eslint dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^5.0.0"
}
```

It seems odd that you'd need this many packages to get eslint working, but this worked for me.